# Shorting transformer leads

Tags: transformer

Sorry for a trivial question. I have a transformer with a tapped secondary coil: 12(blue wire)-0(black wire)-12V(2nd blue wire). I need to use it as a 12V supply source, so can use 0-12VAC (either side of a tap, one blue and the black-ground).I understand that in this configuration I only get a half of the rated current. However, what happens if I short both sides of the tap (both blue wires together). Can I get a full current? or because of the phase difference between the blue wires I get nothing (or maybe even both windings blown?).
Is going for a bigger transformer -  the only option? (I am restricted in space inside the electronic enclosure).

Answer (score 3):

You definitely do *not* want to short the +12 and -12 outputs together. I don't see any reason to believe that using the center tap with one of the others will reduce available current.

If you need DC output from the transformer, you can use all three outputs to get full-wave output with (marginally) less circuitry than a full-wave bridge requires.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhafUL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

If you connect the transformer as so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx2K4d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your output voltage will be approximately \$12 \cdot \sqrt{2} - 0.7\$ V ~= 16VDC (more under a light load).

If you want 12VDC you can add an [LM7812](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM7805.pdf) regulator to the output.

The maximum current you can draw will be approximately the same as the rating of the transformer in this configuration (if the transformer is rated at 24V C.T. at 500mA (12VA) you can draw about 500mA at 16VDC (or 12VDC using the linear regulator [LM7812](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM7805.pdf)). See [here](http://www.hammondmfg.com/pdf/5c007.pdf) for reference. Your regulated output is thus 6W with 2W dissipated by the regulator (it needs a moderate heatsink).

[image]

The 0.33uF capacitor is optional if C1 is close by (an inch or two). The 0.1uF cap is also optional according to many 7812 makers, but it's best to have it on there.

For 500mA you'd want C1 to be something like 4700uF (1V p-p ripple at 0.5A), and proportionally less or more for more or less current. It should have a voltage rating of 25V or higher.